# integer to noise function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, noise, perlin-noise

I am trying to implement a basic perlin noise function (I know there is a library that does just that, I just want to try my own), and I have some problem with the integer to noise function used to generate deterministic noise from integer inputs.

the function I am trying to implement is defined there:
http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/noisegen/index.html#continuousnoise

and my code so far look like this:

```
noise2d :: (Int32, Int32) -> Double
noise2d (x, y) =
    let m = x + y * 57
        n = (shiftR m 13) ^ m
        j = (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) .&. 0x7fffffff
    in  1.0 - (fromIntegral j / 1073741824.0)
```

the code compile but I get the same result for any input, due to the fact that n is evaluated to 0.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from your use of the `^`-operator. In C it is bitwise exclusive disjunction (xor), whereas in Haskell it is exponentiation. So, you just need to change the fourth line to

```
        n = (shiftR m 13) `xor` m
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: Yes that's it! Look's like I need to brush up my C, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your error is

```
n = (shiftR m 13) `xor` m
                  ^^^^^
```

(Instead of the power function `(^)`)